# integer overflow in c++

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

can you explain why i am getting an integer overflow in first code but not in second?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ch "\n"
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    long long int g = (1000000 * 2) * 1000000;
    // long long int k = f * 1000000;
    cout << g % 10000003;
    return 0;
}
```

'''

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ch "\n"
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    long long int f = 1000000 * 2;
    long long int k = f * 1000000;
    cout << k % 10000003;
    return 0;
}
```

second code is giving correct output while first is showing error. error is shown below.

```
 warning: integer overflow in expression of type 'int' results in '-1454759936' [-Woverflow]
    8 |  long long int g = (1000000 * 2) * 1000000;
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: note that its a warning, not an error. Its a warning that you should treat as error, but still the distinction is relevant, because warnings can be missed, errors not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the literals in `(1000000 * 2) * 1000000` are `int` types, and the compiler is warning you that this overflows the `int` on your platform.

It doesn't matter that you are assigning the result of this expression to a different type.

One solution is to use `(2ll * 1000000) * 1000000` which forces the implicit conversion of the other terms.